# Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet mixed mode assembly error

Tags: c#, ax

"FileLoadException was unhandled by user code"
(Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information)

as the matter above.i got exception when try to execute

```
        Axapta axapta;
        AxaptaRecord axaptaRecord;

        List<Vendor> vendors = new List<Vendor>();

        public void Submit(Vendor vendor)
        {

            axapta = new Axapta();
            axapta.Logon(null,null, null, null);
            using (axaptaRecord = axapta.CreateAxaptaRecord("IDS_Pelajar"))
            {
                axaptaRecord.Clear();
                axaptaRecord.InitValue();
                axaptaRecord.set_Field("TenteraPolisNo", vendor.VendorAccount);
                axaptaRecord.set_Field("Poskod", vendor.InvoiceAccount);
                axaptaRecord.set_Field("Keturunan", vendor.Name); 
                axaptaRecord.Insert();
            }
            axapta.Logoff();
            vendors.Add(vendor);
```

i already try to add this line of code in app.config

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

but still it doesn't work.

i have no problem to execute that block of code in console..the exception only pop up when i'm try to execute that block of code in WCF services library

sorry for trouble but i really loss now..Tq 4 help

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of the below help you

[Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information - Release Build](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a5bf31e-df96-4bf1-a846-699da46b62fb/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2050727-of-the-runtime-and-cannot-be-loaded-in-the)

[Handling Mixed Mode Assembly Error in WCF Service Host](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/05/handling-mixed-mode-assembly-error-in-wcf-service-host/)

Being WCF, I feel the 2nd link might prove useful. The config file for WCF Service host is located at C:\Program Files (x86)Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0Common7IDEWcfSvcHost.exe.config and hence making the change in this config file should fix it.

Hope this helps.